# Rails 3.2: Switching from Rspec to Test::Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails, testunit

I created a new Rails 3.2.x application with the -T option for no tests because I wanted to use Rspec for testing.

Now I want to revert it back to Test::Unit. How can I do that such that all of the rake tasks work, and new scaffolds are generated with Test::Unit instead of RSpec test shells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching and hacking, here is what got it to work for me.

1. Remove rspec and rspec-rails from the Gemfile
2. Run "gem list rspec --local", and do a "gem uninstall" for each of those rspec gems.
3. Delete Gemfile.lock
4. rm -r spec/
5. bundle install
6. mkdir test/
7. Add "require 'rails/all'" to config/application.rb
8. Create a file test/test_helper.rb and put the following code in it:

   ```
   ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
   require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
   require 'active_support'
   require 'rails/test_help'
   # require 'factory_girl_rails'  #use if you are using FactoryGirl for fixtures

   class ActiveSupport::TestCase
     # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
     #
     # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
     # -- they do not yet inherit this setting 
     fixtures :all

     # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
   end
   ```

After that, you can generate tests using

```
rails g integration_test SomeStories
```

Or you can just add unit tests under test/unit and then run them with

```
rake test
rake test:recent
```